# Why did Nietzsche like Julius Caesar so much?

Tags: ethics, metaphysics, nietzsche

Nietzsche seems to have a certain fascination with figures like Goethe and Julius Caesar. I was wondering why this is the case. Why, specifically, does Nietzsche look up to Caesar so much. Why does he consider him to be so close to the overman ideal? I would also like to know why he had respect for Brutus. Thank you. I'm very interested in your answers.

Comment: See [Nietzsche and ubermensch](https://books.google.it/books?id=Rw4u68fxYQMC&pg=PA315) and compare his admiration for J.C. and Napoleon.

Comment: You can see the second of the [Untimely Meditations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Untimely_Meditations)  : [On the Use and Abuse of History for Life](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/On_the_Use_and_Abuse_of_History_for_Life#7) (1874), **Ch.7**, for the reference to the "great men".

Comment: I have not seen such comments in Nietzsche, but here goes. Nietzsche thought of himself as a tough guy, and Caesar was a tough guy, so Caesar was great. Then Brutus killed Caesar, making Brutus a tougher guy, and so even greater.

Comment: no-one mentions power without pity. or culture

Comment: Obviously it's just idolization. Perhaps also related to [this](https://edition.cnn.com/2015/07/08/entertainment/serial-killer-lovers-the-seventies/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

In my personal opinion, Nietzsche as almost every philosopher that I know, looked at the mortal life through the concept of syllogisms.

In case of humans, with syllogism you can simply devide people into '*übermensch*' and undermensch (sic!).

And he simply liked the '*über*' ones more that the other :)

**Additional notes:**
In German language prefix *über* has connotation of superiority, transcendence, excessiveness, or intensity. -*mensch* mean man.

As you see this traits match perfectly with the description of Julius Ceasar. That would mean that Nietzsche saw the impersonation of the *Übermensch* concepts in him.

Comment: indeed, my question is why this is.

Comment: Welcome to philosophy and thanks for the answer! Is there any chance you could unpack this a little further -- not in comments but by [editing](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/posts/40894/edit) your answer to indicate why this is a persuasive answer to the question for you, and maybe some pointers towards some research which could confirm it?

Comment: @JosephWeissman thank you for your feedback. I will edit the answer and elaborate further on this topic. I will need to find some free time though, so it might need to wait for a bit.

Comment: @JosephWeissman - answer updated!

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is 'power' 'lack of pity' and 'art' -- the latter being less Caesar like, more Goethe, at least without the Christ like modifier.

He was also very fond of himself, and Nietzsche was, and is, particularly ***influential***, in art. The gloss may help, though Nietzsche, like any philosopher, has phases of thought, and he doesn't just do ethics.